Adding dependency package source code to dist folder in monorepo architecture
We are building a UI library with each component as a package in monrepo.
Let's say we have 3 components comp1, comp2, comp3. If I import comp2, comp3 in comp1, on taking build, all the source code of comp2, comp3 is being added to comp1 dist folder. This is increasing the size of my dist folders.
Expected behaviour:
I want to make comp2, comp3 as the dependencies of comp1 and want to install automatically on installing comp1, but comp1 should not have source code of them.
Folder structure:
|--packages
|---comp1
|----dist
|-----comp1(folder)
|-----comp2(folder)
|-----comp3(folder)
|-----index.js
|----src
|-----Comp1.tsx
|----package.json
|
|---comp2
|----src
|-----Comp2.tsx
|----package.json
|
|---comp3
|----src
|-----Comp3.tsx
|----package.json
|
Can someone help how to achieve this.
I want to make comp2, comp3 as the dependencies of comp1 and want to install automatically on installing comp1, but comp1 should not have source code of them.
